# Input string was not in a correct format , with form 1 and 2

Tags: c#, button

why it says
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Here is my Code

```
 public  int transCode = 0;

        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(TransactionCode) FROM TRANSACTIONS",con);
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
           transCode = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[0].ToString()); // Here is the     line where the problem go
        }

        con.Close();
```

Comment: Have you checked what's inside `rdr[0]`?

Comment: What type is `TransactionCode` in the database? Why do you convert it to string at all? If it's already an `int` use `rdr.GetInt32(0)`. If it's not you have to ask yourself why, since you want to convert it to one.

Comment: Best was of debugging is to use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and enter query in to a new query view.  The debug messages are much better in SSMS than c#.  Check results in SSMS to make sure TransactionCode values are all integers.

Comment: Is possible that you are not converting a number. Try method Int32.tryParse, not parse directly, and use dabugger fot show what is inside rdr[0].

Answer (score 2):

This exception means that the value that is being returned by the `Reader` is not convertible to an `Int32`.  You may have a NULL, or a non-integer `TransactionCode` value.  Try examining the value in a debugger to see what the value actually looks like, or reconsider whether or not it will always be an `Int32` value.